# UPDATE VIEW instead of using UPDATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

Please can someone help me with a query?

I understand that an UPDATE VIEW command also updates the underlying table (at least it does in MySQL). So therefore, why would you want to use this command over an UPDATE TABLE

thanks

Comment: Privileges, triggers, laziness...

Answer (score 0):

Please the mysql manual

> 18.4.3 Updatable and Insertable Views
>
> Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such
>   as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying
>   table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one
>   relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the
>   underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a
>   view nonupdatable. To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it
>   contains any of the following:

If there are calculated values like MIN, MAX, COUNT or TABLE JOIN, no UPDATE is possible. For Details look at MySQL manual

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html